# Hidden Iframe Refresh Ajax Alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I am using a hidden Iframe to refresh a page in the background to keep the access token fresh without a whole page refresh. This work great in all browser but IE, in IE when the refresh happens IE steals the focus from anything on the desktop. So my question is there an ajax alternative to a hidden Iframe or a better way to handle this? This is my code:

```
<iframe Id="hidden" src="https://www.xxxxxxxx.com" 
    style="visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; top: 0;
        height:100%; width:0;
        border: none;" 
    onload="refresh()">
</iframe>
<script>
    function refresh() {
        console.clear();
        setTimeout(refreshCookie, 60000);
        function refreshCookie() {
            document.getElementById('hidden').src = document.getElementById('hidden').src;
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Is the other page on a different domain?  If it is then you'll have cross-origin issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const refresh = () => {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              // Request ok.
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "YOUR.URL", true);
    xhttp.send();
}    

setInterval(refresh, 10000); //refresh every 10 seconds.
```

A basic AJAX request should do.

EDIT: -- As Archer said in the comments of your question, if it is cross-domain then it won't work.

Comment: Add a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` if you want to periodically refresh the page.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to ajax where do I put the url and settimeout?

Comment: @llerdal - you need to check my question in the comments above.  If the page is on a different domain then this will not work.

Comment: I edited my answer. And yes, (thank you Archer), be sure your request is not cross domain.

Comment: @nicovank Ok thank you this worked great, how would you open multiple urls and send them do you have to create a new xmlhttprequest for each url?

Comment: Yes. In this case then you can make a function that does the request, and call it several times with each url as a parameter.